# Insert HTML with JavaScript (Konami Code)

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code. I wanted to display a link following the execution of the Konami Code. The alert works but the link didn't show up...

Can you help me please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
  var kkeys = [], konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65";
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
    if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ) {
      alert("Ajout d'animes à la base de donnée: ACTIVÉ");
      $("<a href='../controlleur/page_ajouter.php'><p>Ajouter un anime à la base</p></a>").insertAfter($('<div id="user_action">'));
      kkeys.length = 0;
    }
  }, true);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not your issue, but keycode has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: What does the $() function do? I do not think that is valid JavaScript.

Comment: You have to append `user_action` in your document first. Then you can use `insertAfter`

Comment: @kojow7 that's jQuery

Comment: @MehdiBounya How can you be sure? The OP did not tag jQuery in his post and does not appear to be including the jQuery library.

Comment: @kojow7 I just assumed as he is using a valid jQuery, but yeah, maybe he just copied the code and doesn't actually include the library, so OP are you including jQuery?

Comment: Please show full code

Comment: Does your code work if you move the `<script>...</script>` to the very end of your document just before you close your `</body>` ?

Comment: @kojow7 what code? I think you are trying to tag OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming based on the fact that you used some jQuery code that you are using jQuery, even though you didn't tag that in the question.)

This is the problematic line:

```
$("<a href='../controlleur/page_ajouter.php'>...</a>").insertAfter($('<div id="user_action">'));
```

`$('<div id="user_action">')` creates a new DOM element, so the above line ends up trying to insert the new link after an element which isn't part of the page.

Assuming there is already a div with id "user_action" in the page, you would want to use a jQuery selector to find the existing element:

```
$("<a href='../controlleur/page_ajouter.php'>...</a>").insertAfter($('#user_action'));
```

Here's a simplified example:

```js
$('<div>this will not work</div>').insertAfter($('<div id="foo">'));
$('<div>this works</div>').insertAfter($('#foo'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo"></div>
```

...and here is your corrected code:

```js
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
  var kkeys = [], konami = "38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65";
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
    if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ) {
      alert("Ajout d'animes à la base de donnée: ACTIVÉ");
      $("<a href='../controlleur/page_ajouter.php'><p>Ajouter un anime à la base</p></a>").insertAfter($('#user_action'));
      kkeys.length = 0;
    }
  }, true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user_action"></div>
```